# oracle concurrent select for update and insert

Tags: sql, oracle, concurrency

I have a table with two columns: k (primary key) and value.
I'd like to:

1. select for update by k, if k is not found, insert a new row with a default value.
2. with the returned value ( existent or new inserted row value) make some processing.
3. update the row and commit.

Is it possible to make this "select for update and insert default value if not found"?

If implement (1) as a select/check if found/insert if not found, we have concurrency problems, since two sessions could make the select concurrently on non existent key, both will try to insert and one of the instances will fail.

In this case the desired behavior is to perform atomically the select/insert and one of the instance perform it and the second one keep locked until the first one commits, and then use the value inserted by the first one.

We implement it always doing an "insert ... if not exist.../commit" before the "select for update" but this implies always trying to insert when it is a unlikely needed.

Is there any way to implement it on one sql sentence?

Thanks!!

Comment: It sounds like you want `merge`, but you don't provide much detail in your question on your exact problem.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is that `merge` does not have a `returning into` option.

Comment: merge solves an "insert or update" problem,, and what I need to solve is an  "select for update or insert". As @eaolson said, if merge had a "returning..." I think could be a solution

Answer (score 1):

`select ... for update` is the first step you should make; without it, you can't "reserve" that row for further processing (unless you're willing to lock the whole table in exclusive mode; if that "processing" takes *no time*, that could also be an option, especially if there are not many users who will be doing it).

If row exists, the rest is simple - process it, update it, commit.

But, if it doesn't exist, you'll have to insert a new row (just as you said), and here's a problem of two (or more) users inserting the same value.

To avoid it, create a function which

- will return unique `ID` value for a new row
- is an autonomous transaction

  - why? Because you're performing DML in it (update or insert), and you can't do that in a function unless it is an autonomous transaction

Users will have to use that function to get the next `ID` value. Here's an example: you'll need a table (`my_id`) which holds the last used ID (and every user who accesses it via the function will create a new value).

Table:

```
SQL> create table my_id (id number);

Table created.
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_id
  2    return number
  3  is
  4    pragma autonomous_transaction;
  5    l_nextval number;
  6  begin
  7    select id + 1
  8      into l_nextval
  9      from my_id
 10      for update of id;
 11
 12      update my_id set
 13        id = l_nextval;
 14
 15    commit;
 16    return (l_nextval);
 17
 18  exception
 19    when no_data_found then
 20      lock table my_id in exclusive mode;
 21
 22      insert into my_id (id)
 23      values (1);
 24
 25      commit;
 26      return(1);
 27  end;
 28  /

Function created.
```

Use it as

```
SQL> select f_id from dual;

      F_ID
----------
         1

SQL>
```

That's it ... code you'll use will then be something like this:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id      number constraint pk_test primary key,
  3     name    varchar2(10),
  4     datum   date
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_id in number)
  2  is
  3    l_id test.id%type;
  4  begin
  5    select id
  6      into l_id
  7      from test
  8      where id = par_id
  9      for update;
 10
 11    update test set datum = sysdate where id = par_id;
 12  exception
 13    when no_data_found then
 14      insert into test (id, name, datum)
 15        values (f_id, 'Little', sysdate);         --> function call is here
 16  end;
 17  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_test (1);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME       DATUM
---------- ---------- -------------------
         1 Little     04.09.2021 20:49:21

SQL> exec p_test (1);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME       DATUM
---------- ---------- -------------------
         1 Little     04.09.2021 20:49:21   --> row was inserted

SQL> exec p_test (1);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME       DATUM
---------- ---------- -------------------
         1 Little     04.09.2021 20:49:30   --> row was updated

SQL>
```

Comment: In my case k is not autogenerated value, so can't use your proposal

Answer (score 0):

See if k is available

SELECT * FROM table
WHERE k = value
FOR UPDATE

If no rows returned, then it doesn't exist. Insert it:

INSERT INTO table(k, col1, col2)
VALUES (value, val1, default))

Comment: If made concurrently by two threads on the same unexistent key, one of the threads will fail on insert.
I'd like to know if there is a way to do this concurrently without failing, where each connection select and insert if not exist atomicaly

Answer (score 0):

Use a sequence to generate a surrogate primary key instead of using a natural key. If you had a real natural key, then it would be extremely unlikely for two users to submit the same value at the same time.

There are several ways to automatically generate primary keys. I prefer to use sequence defaults, like this:

```
create sequence test_seq;

create table test1
(
    k number default test_seq.nextval,
    value varchar2(4000),
    constraint test1_pk primary key(k)
);
```

---

*If you can't switch to a surrogate key or a real natural key:*

Change the "insert ... if not exist.../commit" to a simpler "insert ... if not exist", and perform all operations in a single transaction. Inserting the same primary key in different sessions, even uncommitted, is impossible in Oracle. Although the `SELECT` won't cause a block, the `INSERT` will. This behavior is an exception to Oracle's implementation of isolation, the "I" in "ACID", and in this case that behavior can work to your advantage.

If two sessions attempt to insert the same primary key at the same time, the second session will hang, and when the first session finally commits, the second session will fail with the exception "ORA-00001: unique constraint (X.Y) violated". Let that exception become your flag for knowing when a user has submitted a duplicate value. You can catch the exception in the application and have the user try again.

Comment: k is a natural key, and primary key generation is not an option. And yes, is unlikely but even that needs a proper solution.